# opencv TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.3

I am trying to detect a face using OpenCV. I have a file **recognizer.py** as follows:

```
import cv2

faceDetect = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
rec = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
rec.load('recognizer/trainningData.yml')
id = 0
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        id, conf = rec.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])
        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x, y + h), font, 255, (255, 0, 0))
    cv2.imshow("Face", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I am trying to run this code, the program is running successfully and opening a camera window.

But whenever, I am trying to show my face in front of the camera, the program is terminating with **exit code 1** and showing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prateek/recognizer.py", line 15, in <module>
    id, conf = rec.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Means, I am getting the error on **line 15** which is as follows:

```
id, conf = rec.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem. I am using **Python3** and **OpenCV3.3**.

Comment: Maybe if you could demonstrate the problem in a Jupyter notebook, maybe on Google Colaboratory

Comment: Well, you know the problem statement, so how about doing some debugging? Say, investigate the value of all the variables you use there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have got the solution. The problem with was version of opencv. This code is for **opencv2.4** and I was trying to run it on **opencv3**.

Well, The final code for **opencv3** is as following:

```
import cv2

faceDetect = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
rec = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
rec.load('recognizer/trainningData.yml')
id = 0
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        id= rec.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])
        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x, y + h), font, 255, (255, 0, 0))
    cv2.imshow("Face", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

There is no need to mention the variable **conf**.

**rec.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])** is returning the **id** of the person from the **database**.